# Enable tslint/eslint rule TS2339 (Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y')

Tags: typescript, eslint, tsc

While every topic I can find wants to fix or disable the TS2339 error, I'm trying to get the eslint rules in-sync with typescript rules and I would like to enable it.

In looking at the [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin) project, I cannot seem to find how to enable the TS2339 rule or find the associated name.

You can see the setup what I'm trying to do: [Typescript PlayGround](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.6.2&sourceType=module&code=C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAblwF9dcBjNGqcqnCRpMOfIRICoAcgDSEVKhDT2nAPRqowABZ1E1bcgCuAGwAmUBPGTwoAI2Q6oDLdugBJACIBRKAAoAd10ubWdgKDNkCEQASihiVAsAuicdaAABUEhELnowYABaaJMGcJ5UADM6RiN4YmA6EUDg0JSIqP0AOQB5ABUY3HIAOmJGaCwAZiA&rules=N4XyA&tsConfig=N4XyA)

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
}

const me: Person = {
    name: 'Kenny'
}

// this should error both in the IDE (which it does) and with eslint command line with the @typescript-eslint configuration (which it does NOT)
me.age = 3
```

In following the setup and configuration found here: [Rule Setup](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/type-linting/)

```js
 module.exports = {
   root: true,
   parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
   parserOptions: {
     project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
   },
   plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
   extends: [
     'eslint:recommended',
     'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
     'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
   ],
 };
```